# On Spark DataFrame save to JSON and load back, schema column sequence changes

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark DataFrames and trying to do de-duplication across to DataFrames of same schema.

schema for before saving DataFrame to JSON is like:

```
root
 |-- startTime: long (nullable = false)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
```

Schema of DataFrame after loading from JSON file is like:

```
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- startTime: long (nullable = false)
```

I save to JSON as:

```
newDF.write.json(filePath)
```

and read back as:

```
existingDF = sqlContext.read.json(filePath)
```

After doing unionAll

```
existingDF.unionAll(newDF).distinct()
```

or except

```
newDF.except(existingDF)
```

The de-duplication fails because of schema change.

Can I avoid this schema conversion?
Is there a way to conserve (or enforce) schema sequence while saving to and loading back from JSON file?

Answer (score 0):

Implemented a workaround to convert the schema back to what I need:

```
val newSchema = StructType(jsonDF.schema.map {
  case StructField(name, dataType, nullable, metadata) if name.equals("startTime") => StructField(name, LongType, nullable = false, metadata)
  case y: StructField => y
})
existingDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(jsonDF.rdd, newSchema).select("startTime", "name")
```